# Reverse Proxy for golang docker containers

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, docker-compose

I have three docker containers, each of which has a HTTP endpoint implemented in golang.

I start all three of them via a single `docker-compose.yml` file, like:

```
version: '2'
services:
  first_service:
    build: api/firstService
  second_service:
    build: api/secondService
  third_service:
    build: api/thirdService
```

The endpoints exposed by each of the service is unique. For example:

- first_service listens to /1/api
- second_service listens to /2/api
- third_service listens to /3/api

All the three containers expose their service in port 80.

Is there a way for me to query all the endpoints using a single ip address ? For example:

If I curl: 
`http://myservice/1/*` the requests should go to the first_service
`http://myservice/2/*` the requests should go to the second_service and so on.

I realize that I may have to create a reverse proxy of some sort. But I am not able to find out how to make the configuration with the docker-compose and do the port mapping correctly. I want a solution that works with docker 1.12 onwards, preferably. Service Discovery in docker may be a related topic. But I am not able to get this working as I am a newbie to nginx, service discovery, etc. Any help ?

Comment: Are you using nginx in a container as well?

Comment: No, I am not. But I can use it if it will help.

Comment: I would take a look at https://technologyconversations.com/2016/08/01/integrating-proxy-with-docker-swarm-tour-around-docker-1-12-series/

Comment: another container running nginx would definitely work to solve this

Comment: Do you know how to configure that nginx container ?

Answer (score 1):

Use nginx-reverse-proxy.

It will allow you to direct your traffic based on a virtual host.

A good tool that automates everything is jwilder/nginx-proxy https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy

A good blog showing a detailed usage of how to implement this in the best way is https://blog.florianlopes.io/host-multiple-websites-on-single-host-docker/

Good luck!